# Problem with 4 packages on client/server R installation for the version 3.5.1

Tags: r

### Issue:

We have client/server R installation for about 400 packages for the version 3.5.1.
We are running into problem with 4 packages `- jpeg`, `png`, `tiff` and `rtf`.

When users use these packages to generate the files, showing not available.

#### Troubleshoot done:

```
1. We looked at Linux level and these packages shows installed successfully
2. X11 shows installed and accessible at unix level for other applications
3. when we run capabilities within R, 
     shows that above mentioned 4 packages plus X11 as false (means not available)
4. We re-installed the above 4 packages again ; but dont see any difference.
```

capabilities inside R should be true